# evaluate struts2 tags in java script

Tags: javascript, struts2, tags, eval

I am adding rows to a table using a java scripts function. Each row has textFields and select boxes. I wants to use the struts tags for these controls. When i set innerHTML directly to a tag, no results are shown on the screen. Even i tried to eval function on the string content before setting html, but did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts tags will finally be evaluated to HTML tags, if your JavaScript is in JSP and will be called during page load, your Struts tag will be evaluated and you will be able to see the output,

If you are placing your JavaScript code inside a Java Script file then your Struts tag is not going to be evaluated and you wont be able to see the HTML output, as Struts tag evaluation is carried out by your server not the client, to a web browser there is nothing called as Struts tag it just understands HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use jQuery's `html()` function?